# What are the hardware requirements for Battery monitoring?

Tags: battery, resource-monitoring

I looked at the hardware compatibility list, but there is no mention for a requirement of a battery monitoring functionality in the hardware. But, all phones display the battery level with the BatteryManager API.

Comment: Why are you asking this question? Are you planning to create a hardware (or a custom ROM) that doesn't show battery information?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no particular requirement.

You will get battery monitoring details when you send particular commands to the battery.

That is, the battery **itself** will have hardware for that.